# Magnify image on tap or Long press gesture

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to magnify image on LongPress gesture. i have one scrollview inside that one container view and inside that one ImageView. i want magnify on ImageView. i research a lot but not finding anything helpful.

**Is there any third party api is available?**

Thanks

Comment: check out this one: https://github.com/NYTimes/NYTPhotoViewer

Comment: just change zoomScale of scroll view when gesture is recognized

Comment: Check this : https://coffeeshopped.com/2010/03/a-simpler-magnifying-glass-loupe-view-for-the-iphone. This is really helpful tutorial. And this is old tutorial so you have to replace `[window addSubview:viewController.view];` with `[window setRootViewController:viewController];`

Comment: [Check this out](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ios-magnifyingglass)